# Not Unique Table/Alias Error in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, debugging

I'm trying to pull information out of a few tables to start analyzing what each of these custom property values mean for every entitlement.
I keep going over my sql but cannot understand why I keep getting the Not unique table/alias: 'ep' error.
I've tried using no alias and just the full table name instead. I've validated all columns exist and the join statement has the correct keys as well.

I think the issue is in the FROM or JOIN clauses but I'm not sure what is causing the error specifically.

```
 SELECT ep.endpointname
    ,ep.displayname
    ,ep.description
    ,et.Customproperty1_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty1
    ,et.Customproperty2_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty2
    ,et.Customproperty3_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty3
    ,et.Customproperty4_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty4
    ,et.Customproperty5_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty5
    ,et.Customproperty6_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty6
    ,et.Customproperty7_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty7
    ,et.Customproperty8_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty8
    ,et.Customproperty9_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty9
    ,et.Customproperty10_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty10
    ,et.Customproperty11_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty11
    ,et.Customproperty12_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty12
    ,et.Customproperty13_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty13
    ,et.Customproperty14_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty14
    ,et.Customproperty15_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty15
    ,et.Customproperty16_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty16
    ,et.Customproperty17_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty17
    ,et.Customproperty18_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty18
    ,et.Customproperty19_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty19
    ,et.Customproperty20_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty20
    ,et.Customproperty21_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty21
    ,et.Customproperty22_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty22
    ,et.Customproperty23_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty23
    ,et.Customproperty24_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty24
    ,et.Customproperty25_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty25
    ,et.Customproperty26_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty26
    ,et.Customproperty27_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty27
    ,et.Customproperty28_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty28
    ,et.Customproperty29_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty29
    ,et.Customproperty30_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty30
    ,et.Customproperty31_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty31
    ,et.Customproperty32_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty32
    ,et.Customproperty33_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty33
    ,et.Customproperty34_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty34
    ,et.Customproperty35_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty35
    ,et.Customproperty36_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty36
    ,et.Customproperty37_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty37
    ,et.Customproperty38_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty38
    ,et.Customproperty39_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty39
    ,et.Customproperty40_Label
    ,ev.Customproperty40
    FROM endpoints ep
    ,entitlement_types et
    ,entitlement_values ev
    JOIN endpoints ep ON ep.endpointkey=et.endpointkey
    JOIN entitlement_types et ON et.entitlementtypekey=ev.entitlementtypekey
```

Comment: Your `from` clause does have two different tables aliased as `ep`, so that's the immediate problem. Same goes for `et`. You should not be mixing implicit joins (with the comma in the from clause) and explicit joins (with the join/on syntax), this might not behave as you intend.

Comment: It seems likely that your intended query is ``SELECT ... FROM endpoints ep JOIN entitlement_types et ON ep.endpointkey = et.endpointkey JOIN entitlement_values ev ON et.entitlementtypekey = ev.entitlementtypekey``

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: Huh, okay. So adding all the tables I'm pulling from with an alias in the from clause is considered an implicit join? Just checking my understanding because it makes sense to me to have all the tables listed where I'm pulling from but maybe that is my mistake.